# PostgreSQL encrypt function not found

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL. I've read from the tutorial. I  can successfully `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` the data(I know this is just a basic part).

My problem now is to encrypt the data. I'm searching now for tutorial, but I failed to find the answer of my question. I try this code in "execute arbitrary SQL" (edit: in PgAdmin-III? Some other tool?).

```
INSERT INTO "admin" ("email_address", "password", "role_type", "status") 
VALUES ('encrypt(''sdf'', digest(''secret2'', ''sha256''), ''aes'') ', 'sd', 'admin', 'Active')
```

but the result I get is this

```
ERROR: function encrypt(unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

How can I get this function?

So far, as what I have read, they only show code how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `encrypt` function you refer to is presumably `encrypt(bytea, bytea, text)` from [the bundled `pgcrypto` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html).

See the documentation linked above for usage details.

To load the extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

as a superuser.

Really, though, useful crypto isn't as simple as calling an `encrypt` function. Where do you store the key? Is the database server secure (and if so, why are you encrypting the data)? Could an attacker wrap or replace the `encrypt` function to steal keys? Could they enable query logging and steal the key from the server log? Trigger an error that caused the statement to be logged and steal the key from the error message? etc.

Proper cryptography isn't just a matter of sprinking some encryption secret sauce on the code. You need to profile the possible attackers you want to defend against, what you *don't* want to try to defend against, and what their capabilities might be. Then set up suitable systems based on the attacker's assumed capabilities and the cost/inconvenience/downtime/risk you're willing to assume.

Comment: Is this means I don't need to encrypt my data to my database? I know you have more experience than me and I'm just hoping I can get more info about encryption to the database. Honestly, the documentation makes me confuse now.

Comment: The simple query I know is just select, update, delete and add. But now I found out that we can encrypt the data in the database. I'm now interested to know more about this

Comment: @user3818576 You might want to read http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24379/7788 . Really, if you don't understand what you are trying to *accomplish* by encrypting data, don't do it.

Comment: what version of postgresql? I would like to apply the create extension pgcrypto; but I use postgresql 9.0. I read your answer from other forum, that was a good explanation. But I just want to test it and make a choice someday If I can use it or not.

Comment: @user3818576 pgcrypto has existed in PostgreSQL since at least 8.3, and should be installed by default on most systems. Some Linux systems require you to install a separate "-contrib" package to get it. It's been available via `CREATE EXTENSION` since 9.1, when extensions were introduced. For 9.0 and older you have to use the old style - which @BurhanKhalid showed below . But **you should not be developing new code on PostgreSQL 9.0**. Upgrade! Also, **always mention your PostgreSQL version in the question** - *especially* if it's outdated.

Comment: @user3818576 [It's in the manual for your PostgreSQL version](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/contrib.html). You are on PostgreSQL 9.0. There is no `CREATE EXTENSION` command on 9.0. Since you did not mention your version, I assumed you were on a *current version* that has the `CREATE EXTENSION` command. On your *obsolete* PostgreSQL version, you must load extensions manually. This is why you must always mention your PostgreSQL version - it avoids wastes of time like this.

Comment: thank you craig. I learn a lot from your answer and other forum.

Answer (score 0):

These functions are part of an external module [`pgcrypto`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgcrypto.html) and you have to enable it on the database you want to use these functions.

Once you have installed postgresql, run this command:

```
psql -d <database> -f /usr/share/postgresql/<version>/contrib/pgcrypto.sql
```

Where `<database>` is the name of the database that you are using, and `<version>` with the version of postgresql you have installed.

Comment: Do *not* just run the extension script. In fact, if you attempt to do so, you should get an error telling you to use `CREATE EXTENSION` instead. See the manual.

Comment: @user3818576 In either Windows or other any other platform, just `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;`. But seriously, think hard about what you're really trying to accomplish. Bad encryption is worse than no encryption, it's a false sense of security.

Comment: @craig Now I get it, thanks for you advice man. I just trying to use this function. But my question now, is it necessary to use this?

Comment: @user3818576 Impossible to say without knowing what you're trying to  encrypt, why, when you'll need to decrypt it, etc. That's the point I'm trying to make. There is no simple one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: Hah. Burhan, you were right by accident - userblah DOES need to run the contrib script via `psql` because they're on PostgreSQL 9.0, but didn't mention that anywhere ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT encode(encrypt('content to be encrypted', 'your_secret_key', 'aes-cbc/pad:pkcs')::bytea, 'base64');
SELECT decrypt(decode('NG0AHMsly1L7tJas/tXmOQb/Ju0iYBOrpBmR5lXmHrA=', 'base64'), 'your_secret_key', 'aes-cbc/pad:pkcs');
```

if yout want to encrypt using a query, you have to cast the column like this:

```
SELECT encode(encrypt(t.content::bytea, 'your_secret_key', 'aes-cbc/pad:pkcs')::bytea, 'base64')
from your_table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The command, provided by the accepted answer, does work to fix the problem without any changes to my query or data types:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

However, it is important to know that you need to create the extension while connected to the database you wish to use pgcrypto with.  To connect to your database, in psql (as a superuser):

```
\connect <databasename>
```

And *then* use the **CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;** command.